# Excel Loops to send individual mails based on a column value

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am working on  a VBA automation project for my company and hoping you can help me on the VBA looping part. I am still learning VBA loops and not very good at them yet.

*** Sample code ***
For each cell in ActiveSheet.Cells
Range("A1:A100").Copy  -> how to make this part dynamic based on the oppty lead's name column?
Next cell
*** Sample code ***

Contrary to what some people have suggested in comments below, I don't think Word mail merge can accomplish this as this requires copying pasting an entire range based on the oppty lead filter whereas Word mail merge just creates mails based on the individual rows.

I need a VBA loop that goes through an Excel table and copies-pastes a portion of the table/range from that table based on the column “oppty lead” e.g. for "Abhishek Singh" as oppty lead, only the table/range pertaining to his records gets inserted into the mailer sent to him for his comments.

In a similar manner, the marco then also loops through names of all other oppty leads in the xls and creates individual mails to them with their respective tables/ranges also copied-pasted into those mails.

Thanks in advance for your guidance on how this could be done.

Please find below my sample code but I believe it needs to be expanded further.

Comment: You wouldn't. You would use mail merge instead of VBA. It is the inbuilt system designed to do this.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please note this is not a free code-writing service. You need to provide your code highlighting areas you're having problems with so that people here can help you. Don't worry about being a beginner, everyone has to be a beginner at first.

Comment: Alan, can mail merge copy paste a part of the range into e-mails after filtering it on a specific field? I don't think so. Word mail merge just loops through each row of a table and sends out mails based on the column fields- don't think it can copy paste an entire range based on column filter.

Comment: «can mail merge copy paste a part of the range into e-mails after filtering it on a specific field» You need to clarify what you mean. That said, the inclusion of a DATABASE field in the mailmerge main document might achieve what you're after.

Comment: Cross-posted at: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/excel-loops-to-send-individual-mails-based-on-a-column-value.1151837/
For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Comment: @VishalTayal As macropod said. Potentially yes. However, if the data is badly formatted the answer is to fix the data, not reimplement mail merge. Always use the simplest and most robust solution.

Comment: I stand by my comments. If your data is badly formatted, fix your data. Do not reimplement mail merge.